# JMeter not accepting POST API

Tags: jmeter, bad-request

[image]

Tried to send POST API via Jmeter. Throws me 400 bad req:

[image]

[image]

Set the authorization, content-type, user agent. Made the same replica as I use in postman. But no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the empty row in Header Manager.

Show in View Results Tree the response, the 3 tabs so that we can help more.

If it's working in Postman, put JMeter as a proxy to record the request.

To do it, use Template Recording in JMeter then start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and in postman configure proxy as http://localhost:8080

Comment: Images are attached in my comment. as hyperlink text as : enter image description here

Comment: Yes, user agent was passed incorrectly , that's why the issue was there.

Comment: In this case, you should accept answer and upvote so that it's helpful to others. Thanks